# ScalaTest I get error while loading Suite, Scala signature Suite has wrong version

Tags: scala, maven, dependencies, scalatest, test-suite

I have a maven project with dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And have a test class suite like so:

```
import java.util.{LinkedHashMap => jLinkedHashMap, ArrayList => jArrayList, Arrays}
import org.scalatest._


class NeutralizeEITSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {

    val nEIT = new NeutralizeEIT()

    test("Valid content category 'MiniSeries' is neutralized to 'TV Entertainment':") {
        val result = neutralizedEIT(content_category = "MiniSeries")
        val content_category = getStringValueFromEIT("content_category", result)
        content_category should equal ("TV Entertainment")
    }
}
```

I get an error during compilation that I do not understand:

```
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] C:\PROJECTS\active\Farallon\Hyperion\master\src\test\java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\PROJECTS\active\Farallon\Hyperion\master\target\test-classes at 1454551605523
[ERROR] error: error while loading Suite, Scala signature Suite has wrong version
[INFO]  expected: 5.0
[INFO]  found: 4.1 in Suite.class
[ERROR] C:\PROJECTS\active\Farallon\Hyperion\master\src\test\java\com\mycompany\ese\ingest\NeutralizeEITSuite.scala:9: error: illegal inheritance;
[INFO]  self-type com.mycompany.ese.ingest.neutralizeEITSuite does not conform to org.scalatest.FunSuite's selftype org.scalatest.FunSuite
[INFO] class neutralizeEITSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {
[INFO]                                  ^
[ERROR] C:\PROJECTS\active\Farallon\Hyperion\master\src\test\java\com\mycompany\ese\ingest\NeutralizeEITSuite.scala:9: error: illegal inheritance;
[INFO]  self-type com.mycompany.ese.ingest.neutralizeEITSuite does not conform to org.scalatest.Matchers's selftype org.scalatest.Matchers
[INFO] class neutralizeEITSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {
[INFO]                                                ^
[ERROR] C:\PROJECTS\active\Farallon\Hyperion\master\src\test\java\com\mycompany\ese\ingest\NeutralizeEITSuite.scala:15: error: recursive value result needs type
[INFO]         val content_category = getStringValueFromEIT("content_category", result)
```

I've tried googling the error but no results. I don't have additional org.scalatest dependencies in my pom.xml

Where is this version 4.1 and 5.0 for FunSuite?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by updaing the scala specs dependency in my pom

from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.2_1.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools.testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.2_1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a conflict of `content_category` variable with `content_category` named parameter in line before.

Comment: That did help that last error but my main problem is with this line: `error: error while loading Suite, Scala signature Suite has wrong version` Which version is it loading? is there a conflict? some of my dependencies have dependency on scalatest 0.9 it seems. Could that cause it?

Answer (score 1):

I came to this one 5 years later, so for anyone arriving here via Google... the answer these days is that you probably have an old version of org.specs in your pom.xml (possibly because you copied and pasted from an old source), alongside the new org.scalatest library.

If you have both, the fix is to delete this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
  <version>[Some version]</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and leave only this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(Where the _2.11 is replaced with the Scala version you're using, and the 3.2.9 is replaced with the ScalaTest version you're using.)